# excel macros visual basic if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in a macro of Excel.
The code is:

```
If Sheets("Summary of Quantities").Range(ColARange).Value = "Y" And Sheets("Formatted SOQ").Range("ColXRange"). = Sheets("Summary of Quantities").Range("ColDRange") Then
```

I get the error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

The problem started when I added in the:

```
And Sheets("Formatted SOQ").Range("ColXRange"). = Sheets("Summary of Quantities").Range("ColDRange") Then
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an extra `.` after `Range("ColXRange"). Not sure what the values refer to, but try this perhaps:

```
If Sheets("Summary of Quantities").Range(ColARange).Value = "Y" And Sheets("Formatted SOQ").Range("ColXRange") = Sheets("Summary of Quantities").Range("ColDRange") Then
```